# React 15 and 16 Components in a dashboard application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables

I have a dashboard application that hosts multiple web components.

Each of these web components use React 15 but I would like to contribute a web component that uses React 16 to the dashboard.

When I tried to do this, I started getting React errors because when you have multiple versions of React on your page, their globals interfere with each other.

One successful workaround I tried was putting my React 16 component inside an `iframe` element so it doesn't share the same global space as the one that is being used by the React 15 components.

However, this feels like a hacky workaround to me. And whether it actually is or not, I was hoping there would be another way to achieve this same effect?

Comment: And did using only react 16 broke everything ? because if you are on react v15.6 and have no warning then everything should work fine with react v16

Comment: Can you post your code? Would also be interesting to see, how you import/integrate both React dependencies in your bundle. Do you include them as global script?